# Changing A UIView Variable From ViewController In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've been stumbling along with Swift lately, and have come across a concept that I think I understood, but can't seem to get it working properly.

In my app, I have a ViewController with a View that I've added in IB.  I've set the Custom Class of my View to be "RingView", which lives in my RingView.swift file (for context, RingView draws a ring).

This is technically working fine, as my ring is rendered appropriately when I run the app.  What I'm trying to do is to set the width of the ring's line and the stroke color programmatically *from* my ViewController.swift file.  While I'm not getting any errors when I build, despite me setting the lineWidth to 10, for example, the width of the line is always 1 when I build.

**RingView.swift**

```
class RingView: UIView {

var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1

var strokeColor = UIColor(red: 147.0/255.0, green: 184.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

let circlePathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let circleRadius: CGFloat = 105.0

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    configure()
}

func configure() {

    circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
    circlePathLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    circlePathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    circlePathLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor

    layer.addSublayer(circlePathLayer)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

func circleFrame() -> CGRect {
    var circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2*circleRadius, height: 2*circleRadius)
    circleFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(circlePathLayer.bounds) - CGRectGetMidX(circleFrame)
    circleFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMidY(circlePathLayer.bounds) - CGRectGetMidY(circleFrame)
    return circleFrame
}

func circlePath() -> UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: circleFrame())
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
    circlePathLayer.path = circlePath().CGPath
}

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var RingViewInner: RingView!


var detailItem: Minion? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {

    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail = self.detailItem {

        //Set the label for the title name
        if let label = titleLabel {
            label.text = detail.title!
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    RingViewInner?.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.0).CGColor
    RingViewInner?.lineWidth = 10
    RingViewInner.setNeedsDisplay()

    //Show the configured context of data
    self.configureView()
}
}
```

Any thoughts would be immensely appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You may want to override `drawRect()` in your custom view class to do the drawing of your view. Don't know if that'll solve you issue or not, but it may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to explain this with the help of the following example where I have a simple view with an UIImageView inside of it and later on I want to set its image from ViewController. Following code is for the view-

```
class ImagePreviewView: UIView {
    var imgView: UIImageView!
    var img: UIImage!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        imgView=UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        self.addSubview(imgView)
    }

    func setImage(img: UIImage){
        self.imgView.image=img
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.backgroundColor=UIColor.black
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now the code for the ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        imagePreviewView = ImagePreviewView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width-sideStripWidth, height: self.view.frame.height-140))
        self.view.addSubview(imagePreviewView)
    }

    //call this function to set image of imagePreviewView
    func changeImage(img){
        imagePreviewView.setImage(img: img)
    }
}
```

The changeImage function calls the setImage function in imagePreviewView to change the image. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the variable global, for example you can put it out side the class "ViewController"